# How to use the git bash "ssh" functionality in cmd.exe

Tags: git, terminal, cmd, git-bash

I am able to use git from my windows terminal since i have added git to its PATH. I can do "git pull", "git push" etc. straight from the terminal, but i somehow can't use the ssh feature, which only works in the git bash terminal.
Is it possible to use the git bash "ssh" command in the windows terminal? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer, ssh is located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe** . However, that is the same location as git.exe, so if you system is the same, your PATH reference should work.

Alternatively, you could download any of the many Windows based [ssh clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) . I like [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), but any of them will do.

Comment: when I cd to navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\, and then tried writing "ssh.exe xxxx@xxxx.com" it worked. But isn't there a easier way?

Comment: If `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\` is in your PATH, you should be able to run ssh.exe from any directory on the command prompt. See http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm for how to set up your PATH. If you want easier, download Putty, with it you can maintain a list of all you SSH hosts.